# why using stack data structure for storing primitive values instead of linked lists or arrays ?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, data-structures, stack

Since Stacks internally uses either Linked Lists / Arrays, why don't java directly store primitive values in Linked Lists / Arrays instead of Stacks ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking about, I'm afraid. I suspect you may be confusing "the stack" (an area of memory, compared with the heap) and "java.util.Stack" (a Java collection class).

Comment: @JonSkeet:  But both are same right ? Both are FILO.

Comment: Any kind of `Stack` is based on `LIFO`. The Stack has some policy for `push` and `pop` operations which guaranties stack to be `LIFO`.  In many situations like parsing and calculating a math statement with some parenthesis, stack is very useful because you don't need to worry about the way of pushing and popping businesses.

Comment: You mentioned `FILO` **First In Last Out** is the same as `LIFO` **Last In First Out** but is `LIFO` is more common. If you leave the `Push` and `Pop` operations to your code and use something like `List` instead you should do the same in your code. So don't re-create the Wheel from scratch.

Comment: In just those abstract terms, they're the same. In almost all other ways, they're very, very different.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is that generics are a compile time feature and all implementation of generics use the same code, they are all `List<? extends Object>` and can be cast to this type.  However `List<int>` is not a List of Object and would need it's own code generated on demand (something the compiler doesn't do).

Also consider what is the parent of `List<Object>` and `List<int>` it could be a `List<*>` or something like that which has a `size()` method.  This means adding a parent to `List<object>` which it previously didn't have and doing it for data types which have already been compiled.  e.g. say you have your own Stack implementation in a JAR when the JVM designers have never seen and without re-compiling you JAR you now want a `Stack<int>` which is a class which never existed before, where does it go? what should it be called? If the compiler creates it and you release it in one JAR but later you compile it again for another JAR you have two versions of the same class.

These means that most likely this class will need to be understood at compile time for the `javac` but actually created on demand at runtime to ensure there is one, most up to date version of the classes.

Supporting primitive generics is non-trivial but can be done.  In fact they are looking to do it in Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a nice question on SO. 
Let me start with `java.util.Stack` which extends `Vector` and have certain methods which internally calls the methods defined in `Vector` class. (For ex: `removeElementAt(..)`,  `addElement(..)` and so on.

The `Vector` implementation involves "`Array`" as you rightly said.(if you consider `jdk` version)

Basically `java.util.Stack` works on the principle of **LIFO** which makes it an wonderful `data structure`. (with simple `push` and `pop`)

Now coming back to your question why java doesn't make use of array for `stack memory`. Let me give you a brief overview of **stack memory**.

`Stack Memory` contains method specific values that are short-lived and references to other objects in the `heap` that are getting referred from the method used by `threads`.

If you consider your program flow the *great* `main()` will be called first and all subsequent nested method calls will be followed by it. So this is how `stack` should look like if you only consider methods in `stack memory` of your program flow:

```
main() <----- 1st call

method1() 
main() <------ 2nd call

method2()
method1() 
main()  <------ 3rd call
```

So here if you visualize all control of you program should come back to `main()`. The principle of **LIFO** is certainly best choice here. When you have a handy `data structure` to do that why to reinvent the wheel and make use of `Array`?

**Note :** Ideal option to visualize read out a `.class` file.